# Using >= or value - 1?

Tags: c++, optimization

Say I'm checking for if a value is greater than or equal to a certain value and the current values I'm comparing are integers.  In C++, would it be more optimal to do something like:

```
if(value > threshold - 1)
...
```

or this

```
if(value >= threshold)
...
```

My thinking is that the call to `>=` adds an extra stack frame, but then again a call is made when using `-` for the subtraction operation.  While I know the performance difference is likely negligible, which is *technically* more optimal?

Comment: Do you find one easier to read than the other?  Have you checked the assembly for both versions?

Comment: Neither is faster than the other in any meaningful sense, and unless you have a profiler that says that the comparison is a bottleneck in your code, you should not worry about such minor things. Premature optimization is a total waste of time and effort that can be better spend actually accomplishing something useful.

Comment: There is no such thing as "technically more optimal".

Comment: And *"My thinking is that the call to >= adds an extra stack frame ..."*.  It is not a call, and it does not add an extra stack frame.   (And even if it was a call, the call *could* have been optimized away by inlining.)

Comment: The [As-If Rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) says the compiler is allowed to swap `if(value > threshold - 1)` for `if(value >= threshold)`, vice-versa, or some other crazy smurf you haven't even thought of yet if it believes there is an advantage. I wouldn't worry about this one.

Comment: neither `>=` nor `-` are function calls, so neither adds another stack frame.  You're worrying about nanoseconds, at best, and any decent optimizing compiler won't care which  you pick anyways.

Comment: I got my first optimizing compiler back in the late 1980s.  The optimizer did every trick in my bag of assembly language tricks and then some.  Since then, I haven't written nearly anything in assembly.  The lessoned learned:  the optimizer is mind-boggling amazing.  Don't try to second guess it.  Profile, profile, profile.

Comment: @Donnie Generically speaking then, how should I refer to operations being done with logical operators and arithmetic operators?  Do things change when I'm referring to operators that I've overloaded myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first has **undefined behavior** if `threshold` is **signed** and is the most negative value of its type.  That might disqualify it immediately, but if you know that case is impossible, it is therefore *at least as fast* as the `>=` version since the compiler is obliged to produce the same answer but in only a subset of cases.  In practice, however, equivalent assembly is produced: any sensible architecture has enough comparison instructions such that some combination of swapping the inputs and switching between strict and non-strict inequalities can implement either without actually subtracting 1.

If `threshold` is **unsigned**, the first is well-defined for all input values but is **inequivalent** to the `>=` version.  Again, that inequivalence might compel the choice; otherwise, the first is **slower** on typical architectures because it actually has to perform the subtraction to achieve that difference in behavior.

Answer (score 2):

If `threshold` is the smallest repersentable value, then `threshold - 1` will have the wrong behaviour (opposite of desired behaviour [assuming desired behaviour is what `>=` provides] if unsigned, or undefined behaviour if signed). `>=` doesn't have this problematic corner case.

Another consideration is that `value >= threshold` has the same behaviour for floating point, while the behaviour of `- 1` is different. This makes `>=` more general.